# MongoDB -check if nested array record doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document which looks like this:

```
"id":X,
"name": "X",
"email": "X",
"shows": ["id":X, ,"name":X,"season":X,"ep_id":X, "active" : true/false]
```

Inside shows can be many records with unique ID.

Given a show id,how can i check if active field is true or not for this record?
I want to do some action if the value of the field is false.

I've tried this but it gives me the full document.

```
userM.find({id: userID, 'shows.id': showID,'shows.active':true})
```

Thanks

Edit: 
I managed to find a way using forEach manipulation on the query results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

db.userM.find(
   { shows: { $elemMatch: { "id": "X", "active":true } } }
)